# Don't know what kind of Bean i should define in the code

Tags: java, spring

New at Java and I'm coding Backend for an email and registration application. I have everything running with PostgreSQL as my DB manager and Postman for post and get tests and everything was running fine yesterday. But today I re-opened my editor and it gives me an error telling me to define a type of bean

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.email.EmailService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code looks like this

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmailService implements EmailSender{

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(EmailService.class);

    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Override
    @Async
    public void send(String to, String email) {
        try {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper =
                    new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "utf-8");
            helper.setText(email, true);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject("Confirm your email");
            helper.setFrom("aiurhelp@hotmail.com");
            mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("failed to send email", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException("failed to send email");
        }
    }
}
```

and my dependencies in my *pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>aiurDB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Aiur</name>
    <description>back end login for aiur</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can u please use `@Autowired private final JavaMailSender mailSender;` and tell me the result ?

Comment: And delete `@AllArgsConstructor`

Comment: @HadesZazif still giving me the same error

Comment: Are you defining `JavaMailSender` bean in any of `Configuration` classes? Spring will only provide that bean if you have `spring.mail.host` or `spring.mail.jndi-name` property defined.

Comment: As @Setu mentioned, you need to define the properties. Launch your application using `--debug` to get a report that tells you exactly why each possible automatic bean is or is not activated.

Comment: I'm using intellij and it has a built-in debugger but when i run it with the debug it just gives me the same error @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: @Setu by `spring.mail.host` you mean something like `smtp.gmail.com` ?

Comment: @Jairkaran I'm not saying to use the debugger. I'm saying to pass the parameter to your application (perhaps there's a "debug output" checkbox in your IntelliJ launch dialog) so that it produces an analysis for you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared any bean with type `JavaMailSender`. Spring container can't find any Beans with this type and prints typical messages for it.
Try to declare `@Bean` or `@Component` or `@Service` with the type `JavaMailSender`.
Also, for final dependencies more correct use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`
And if you use Spring 4 necessary to add `@Autowire` above constructor or `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))` for the lombok usage.

Comment: could you maybe show me where i should declare the bean? i have been struggling with this.